# How to add icon in search bar in react-autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, react-autocomplete

I am using [react-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete) for search and I want to add search icon to autocomplete component

My current code is

```
import Autocomplete from "react-autocomplete";
import searchIcon from "../images/search-icon.svg";
......
......

        <InputGroup className="searchbar">
           <div style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex" }}>
              <Autocomplete
                getItemValue={(item) => item.key}
                items={suggestionItems}
                renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
                  <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? '#eee' : 'transparent' }} key={item.key}>
                    {item.label}
                  </div>
                }
                
                value={queryText}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onSelect={this.onSelect}
                autoHighlight={false}
                inputProps={{ style: { width: "100%", height: "100%", padding: "6px 12px" }, placeholder: "Enter a query here"}}
                wrapperStyle={{ width: "100%" }}
                ......
                ......
           </div>
        </InputGroup>
```

My end goal is to have something similar to stackoverflow search bar like below:

[image]

I tried to add the search icon inside the placeholder like this:

```
inputProps={{ style: { width: "100%", height: "100%", padding: "6px 12px" }, placeholder: " Enter a query here"}}
```

But the icon will disappear when typing..I want the icon stay there inside the search bar no matter what, exactly like what stackoverflow search bar does.

Does anybody know how I can make it work with react-autocomplete ?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can inspect the stack Overflow search bar then you'll see the searchIcon is an SVG Image. So basically you can render the search bar with the below pattern

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    input{
      border:none;
      outline:none;
      font-size:16px
    }
    .search-container{
      border:1px solid;
      width:fit-content;
      background:white;
      padding:5px;
      border-radius:5px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="search-container">
<img src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/585e4ae1cb11b227491c3393.png" height="15px" widht="15px" alt="a" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search...."/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will do the job
[image]